# How can I repair the boot loader on my laptop?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I had removed my HD from a Dell laptop and accessed it with an external HD port on another computer. Though after returning it to the Dell laptop, it will no longer boot. The PC came pre-installed with Windows 7 and I do not have an installation disk. None of the contents of the original install have been removed or modified.

If I use another laptop running Windows 7 to create a repair/recovery disk, would I be able to use it on my Dell to repair the boot sector?

How can I repair the bootmgr?

It's frustrating knowing there's a perfectly good operating system there that wont boot.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

It is best to obtain a Windows 7 recovery CD with same bit version as your installed Windows 7 system - 32 bit or 64 bit.

Simply boot the recovery CD and run "Startup Repair" up to three consecutive times with rebooting after each run until no errors are reported.

Comment: Try this first. Since you dont have the installation CD, download your version from digital river: http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/    and yes, these are legal!

Answer (score 0):

Yes a repair disk should fix your issue.

See [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) for some info about the steps to take.

Via the install/recovery disk.

> Repair your computer > Next > Command Prompt > bootrec /fixmbr or bootrec /fixboot